# Unable to restore an MSSql Database from an Azure Storage backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure, restore

We have a simple sql script to restore an MSSql DB from an Azure storage blob. We backup our PROD DB to Azure Storage.

Trying to run this script (which we swear *used* to work a while ago).. now errors:

> Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "https://<{snip}.blob.core.windows.net/full/{snip}.bak:" The specified URL points to a Block Blob. Backup and Restore operations on Block Blobs are not permitted..
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

This `.bak` file is generated via MSSql using the built in Maintenance Plan functionality and does a full backup to Azure, once a week:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [<snip>]
TO URL = N'https://<snip>.blob.core.windows.net/full/<snip>.bak' 
WITH CREDENTIAL = N'<snip>' ,
NOFORMAT,
NOINIT,
NAME = N'<snip>',
SKIP,
REWIND,
NOUNLOAD,
COMPRESSION,
STATS = 10
```

Here's what the Azure GUI says for this destination blog in Azure Storage:

[image]

and the script we've used:

```
RESTORE DATABASE <snip> -- |||||--CHANGE--|||||
FROM URL = 'https://<snip>.blob.core.windows.net/full/<snip>.bak' -- |||||--CHANGE--|||||
WITH CREDENTIAL = '<snip>',
MOVE N'<snip>' TO <snip>,
MOVE N'<snip>_log' TO <snip>,  
NOUNLOAD,  
REPLACE,  
STATS = 1
GO
```

Is this a problem with our restore script OR we are incorrectly backing up FULL to azure?